# Why isn't BeautifulSoup working? (Python 2.7.10)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import urllib.request
r = urllib.request.urlopen('http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
print type(soup)
```

I get the message "urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden"

I'm a complete beginner when it comes to modules, so I have no idea what I'm doing. sorry.

Comment: Because the error is raised before it is called, by `urlopen...read`. Apparently the site does not like programmatic access.

Comment: So you are saying it is because of the website I want to look at? I get errors no matter what url I choose.

Comment: Are those errors in any way related to what you got from this one? It is because of the website: the important part in the error is **Forbidden**.

Comment: @frightenedeyes You cannot get HTTP 403 errors from *every* possible URL (including Google or Facebook) unless you are using a proxy of some sort and *that* proxy is denying you outgoing access or a response. Alternatively, check your firewall settings - for whatever reason, you may be blocking your own connection.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to specify the UserAgent:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ret = requests.request(
    'GET',
    'http://www.aflcio.org/Legislation-and-Politics/Legislative-Alerts',
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/602.4.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0.3 Safari/602.4.8'}
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(ret.text, "html.parser")
print type(soup)
```